# Allow access to specific file but exclude files of the same name in subdirectories in .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have the following directory structure:

- `folder`

  - `example`

    - `index.php`
  - `.htaccess`
  - `index.php`
  - `other.php`

I want to deny access to everything within `/folder`, except for `/folder/index.php`. I can deny access to all files, and then allow access to `index.php`, but this also allows access to any `index.php` which is in a subdirectory of `.htaccess`.

```
Order allow,deny
Deny from all
<FilesMatch ^index\.php$>
    Allow from all
</FilesMatch>
```

How can I modify `.htaccess` to only allow access to `index.php` which is in the same directory of the `.htaccess`? Note that all folder and/or file names could change, excluding `index.php` and `.htaccess`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this `mod-rewrite` rule to deny access to all files except `/index.php` in `/folder` .

```
 RewriteEngine  on
 #check if the file exists
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
 #check if the file is being requestsed from /folder
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/folder/
 #deny access to all existant files except index.php
 RewriteRule !folder/index\.php - [L,R=403]
```

This will return a 403 forbidden error for all files excluding `/index.php` if accessed by browser.
The rule above will only apply to files in the `/folder` . If you want to deny access to all (including files and subfolders ) simply remove the first condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f` .